# Unity won't load at login, but starts in Classic after running unity --reset

Tags: 11.04, unity

I have a Dell Latitude E6400 laptop. I've had Ubuntu 10.04 64-bit working for years. I decided to update to 11.04 (via 10.10) and it's fine except Unity won't load. I get the backdrop, the WiFi network notification, and I can see the mouse pointer. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> gives me the restart/shutdown/etc. options.

If I select Ubuntu Classic at the login screen, it loads fine.  I've tried fiddling with a few `ccsm` settings but it makes no difference. I've  disabled GNOME compatibility, and enabled the Unity plugin. If I type:

```
unity --reset
```

from classic mode it loads up Unity, suggesting there's no obvious problem with the drivers. There are some error messages but I lose the ability to move windows around at this point and I don't seem to be able to cut/paste the messages.

I did fiddle with Compiz in the past to get the appearance menu to allow me to select `none` for animations and have it stick. Perhaps I have to uninstall/reinstall something?

This is very annoying - it seems like I'm very close to having it working but I don't know what to try next. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do a clean install from a Live-CD to get a working install. As an online upgrade, both metacity and unity were never started.

Comment: I was kind of hoping that getting a different set of icons/menus appearing didn't require a full reinstall.  That's more a Windows thing, isn't it?

Comment: I did a reinstall. It works now.  I don't like Unity one little bit but I'll check it out and give it a fair chance, otherwise I'll be installing Debian.

Answer (score 0):

Press ALT+F2, type

```
ccsm
```

and press ENTER

Click to preferences from compiz main window

Select Default settings for unity profile, close the compiz window.

Open a terminal and type this:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install ubuntu-desktop unity
sudo reboot
```

Login to Ubuntu session

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that, but it's made no difference.  I choose 'ubuntu' on the login screen, which used to mean it would try to log on using Unity, but now it just logs on normally; succesfully, but without Unity.  I'm going to see if I can find some more settings to experiment with.